# Непрозрачная графика на прозрачном Jframe

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

возникла необходимость отображения непрозрачной графики на прозрачном Jframe c использованием BufferStrategy (если это вообще возможно).

```
public class TransFrame extends JFrame {

BufferStrategy bufs;

public TransFrame() {
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255));
    this.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(TransFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);

    this.createBufferStrategy(2);
    bufs = getBufferStrategy();

    Timer t = new Timer(1000 / 30, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            render();
        }
    });

    t.start();

}

public void render() {
    Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D) bufs.getDrawGraphics();
    gr.setColor(Color.RED);
    gr.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    gr.dispose();

    bufs.show();

  }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё рисуется ,но когда меняю прозрачность Background то графика пропадает...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?